# Transition property weird effect on border size on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to have a border-bottom effect on hover.

I am using transition property on hover, however after the transition-duration is over the border size changes/reduces by a pixel or so, which seems weird. Please help fix this and also would love to know the reason for this effect.

[image]

HTML -

```
<nav class="navbar">
   <ul>
     <li>
       Home
     </li>

     <li>
       About us
     </li>

     <li>
       Contact us
     </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS -

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
    width: 90vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

.navbar ul li:hover {
    color: orangered;
    border-bottom: 4px solid orangered;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Here is the code - https://codepen.io/rawn01/pen/bGBmBdK

Comment: What browser does this happen on?

Comment: chrome and firefox both

Comment: I tested on chrome 88.0.4324.190 (64bit) and everything works well.

Comment: You nav li are being affected by the number of letters in them. 
maybe try to increase 'home' and 'about us' to the size of 'contact us'

Comment: I guess its a problem with the browser then, its working on perfectly fine for me on Brave as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this happening is how the browser optimizes rendering. For animating / transitioning effects it often separates the affected element into a separate "composition layer" for performance reasons.

You can try several ways to attempt to fix the graphical issue:

1. add [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) attribute in order to tell the browser to keep the element on a separate layer
2. modify your `transition: all 1s` to a more specific one (e.g. `transition: color 1s, border-bottom-color 1s`). Also make sure to only modify the `border-bottom-color` attribute, not the whole `border-bottom` attribute with size and type (even though it stays the same)

Comment: `border-bottom-color` fixes the issue for me. Thanks!